# Google Maps Sidebar Render Issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, sidebar

I wonder whether it's possible that someone could help me please with a problem I've been trying to solve for over a week now.

I'm using [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/mylocationstest.html) page to try and implement sidebar functionality to my Google map with the list entries and associated map markers switched on and off via category checkboxes.

I can get the markers to appear and disappear via the checkboxes, but I can't get the sidebar to render on the page.

As I said I've spent a lot of time on this and I seem to be going round in circles and I just can't work out where I'm going wrong.

I just wondered whether it's at possible that someone could take a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Sincere thanks and kind regards

Comment: why do you mean by: I can't get the sidebar to render on the page
do you want the side bar to part of the map ??
if so then check this : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomExample

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. The page currently shows the map, and then two checkboxes on the left hand side. Underneath the checkboxes there should, if I could get it to work, a sidebar that is created lisiting the details of the markers which appear on the map. I hope this clarifies it a little better. Kind regards.